# inapp billing error: "something went wrong on our end. please try again "

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I get error:

> "something went wrong on our end. please try again"

although I put in my code the true product ID but when I use the test product ID it works.

Here's my code:

```
BillingProcessor bp;

...

bp = new BillingProcessor(this,"MY LICENSE KEY FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE", this);

...

bp.purchase(MainActivity.this,"com.new.ke");
```

I use [this library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Please edit and ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

This occured to me when I was sending some test data in `setObfuscatedProfileId` and `setObfuscatedAccountId` . I removed test data and kept some valid data and it started working again (data which will be unique every time)

```
val flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
        .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
        .setObfuscatedProfileId(userProfileId)  //valid user profileId/some id
        .setObfuscatedAccountId(id) // valid user account/some id
        .build()
    val response=
        billingClient?.launchBillingFlow(activity, flowParams)
```

Comment: I am running into same problem. Before hashing obfuscatedId value, it works. but throwing error after hashing it. No idea why....

Answer (score 0):

```
bp.purchase(MainActivity.this,"com.new.ke");
```

should be

```
bp.purchase(MainActivity.this,"product_id");
```

`product_id` is the one from your google dev account for that item.

Hope it helps.